# Natural pauses when reading and speaking

Tags: grammar, usage

For example in a sentence like this which I found online looking this up:

お盆は祖先をまつる期間なので、祖先の霊を迎える前にお墓を掃除するのは大切なことです。

As a native speaker where would you naturally pause? 
I am not sure where to mentally pause when reading and that kind of mess with my ability to comprehend sentences in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read it like this:

> お盆は祖先をまつる期間なので、(pause)祖先の霊を迎える前にお墓を掃除するのは(small pause)大切なことです。

or maybe like this, when reading very slowly:

> お盆は(small pause)祖先をまつる期間なので、(big pause)祖先の霊を迎える前に(small pause)お墓を掃除するのは(pause)大切なことです。

I read it this way because I parse the sentence this way:

［お盆は祖先をまつる期間なので］、［｛（祖先の霊を迎える前に）お墓を掃除するのは｝大切なことです］。

Comment: Thanks. 
So could you give me any advice when to pause?  
For example I heard it a lot after は, any other advice?

Comment: そうですね…やっぱり、「意味のつながり」を考えることですかね・・例えば、relative clause とか noun clause などは、あまり切らないで繋げて読む、とかですかね・・（例：「先祖をまつる期間」とか「祖先の霊を迎える前にお墓を掃除するの」とか「英国王室と‌​‌​‌‌​​ガチンコでぶつかり合ってる魔術結‌​社」とか。。）あと、文全体を修飾する副詞句は、切るとか（「よりによって」とか・・）ですかね・・

Comment: 「「意味のつながり」を考えることですかね。」と言うのは大事だ思います。読んでいる時relative clauserelative clause とか noun clause とか 「は」は僕を悩ませて分からなくなる場合が多い。Relative pronounがない言葉である日本語は、僕にとってはClausesが多いの場合にそれを連続して意味が変わる事が難しい。

Comment: そうですね・・。日本語母語話者も同じで、意味がわからないと、自然に読むことはとても難しいです。また、意味が分かっていても、ベテランアナウンサーのように100％完璧に正しく朗読するのは、（特に、初めて見る文章では、）普通の日本人でもかなり難しいと思います。（アナウンサーも、本番前によく練習してますし・・）

Comment: For example in a sentence like this 急速に展開していた姿を円筒形へ戻していく「敵」を正確に狙い、さらに歩を進めていく。
The context is: A girl is running away from an enemy which can change shape.  
I know that this are nested clauses, by this I mean:[[急速に展開していた]>姿を円筒形へ戻していく]>「敵」を正確に狙い、さらに歩を進めていく。
So every part in the brackets would stop having a role when it reaches the noun it modifies, correct?
I can't help but look at it like this though:[急速に展開していた姿]を円[筒形へ戻していく「敵」]を正確に狙い、さらに歩を進めていく。
As if [急速に展開していた姿] and [筒形へ戻していく「敵」] where 2 different sentences with no connection.  
How would you read a sentence like this?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is parsed: ｛（急速に展開していた）姿を円筒形へ戻していく｝敵を正確に狙い・・・ → ｛XXをYYに戻していく｝敵を狙い・・, so I would read 急速に展開していた姿を円筒形へ戻していく敵を正確に狙い(pause)、さらに歩を進めていく。, pausing only once. I wouldn't put a pause in ｛急速に展開していた姿を円筒形へ戻していく｝敵 since it's a long relative clause.　（｛急速に展開していた｝姿 is also a relative clause, so you wouldn't put a pause in 急速に展開していた.）

Comment: That is really helpful.  I tought that in a sentence with relative clause you should pause after 敵 (in this sentence) and that apparently makes me think that those two sentences are separated while they are connected. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A good tip for non-native speakers is to pause regularly after particles or grammar structures (in this sentence, for example, at は, を, なので, 前に, and のは). Usually when Japanese people try to enunciate their sentences they will follow this strategy, which although it doesn't sound 100% natural, should get you started on the right path.

Comment: Thanks.  
How would you pause in a sentence with many nested relative clauses?   
Would you pause after every verb or after every noun modified by the preceding verb?

Comment: Good question! Usually the pronunciation I mentioned is reserved for the sentence at hand, and since relative clauses are considered as "part of the nouns they modify", you would go through the entire clause + noun up to the particle/grammar form attached to the noun.

For example,

- お弁当を食べた子供が / 公園で / 遊んでいる。

Edit: sorry about my formatting, I'm new here.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I understood it perfectly. How about a sentence like this "「人がさんざん誘惑しまくって『イギリスのためになる』方向へ所属を移させようとしていたのに!!　よりにもよって英国王室とガチンコでぶつかり合ってる魔術結社と繋つながりを持つだなんてーっ!!」"  Where would you pause? 
I know this might sound like a stupid question, but it would be really helpful.

Comment: 「人が / さんざん / 誘惑しまくって /『イギリスのためになる』方向へ / 所属を / 移させようとしていたのに!!　よりにも / よって / 英国王室と‌ / ​ガチンコで / ぶつかり合ってる魔術結社と / 繋つ‌​ながりを / 持つだなんてーっ!!」Sort of like this. Mostly it's about getting used to identifying the different little "packages" where words are stuck together with particles or the like. Eventually, practice will refine your reading to the extent where you can immediately notice them.

Comment: 「人がさんざん誘惑しまくって(pause)イギリスのためになる方向へ所属を移させようとしていたのに!!　よ‌​‌​りにもよって(pause)英国王室と‌​‌​‌​ガチンコでぶつかり合ってる魔術結‌​社と繋がりを持つだなん‌​てーっ!!」‌または、「人がさんざん誘惑しまくって(pause)イギリスのためになる方向へ(small pause)所属を移させようとしていたのに!!　よ‌​‌​りにもよって(pause)英国王室と‌​‌​‌​ガチンコでぶつかり合ってる魔術結‌​社と(small pause)繋がりを持つだなん‌​てーっ!!」‌​のように読むといいと思います‌​。基本的に、意味の切れ目で切ります。